# Webhooks from Zapier in F# not working

Tags: f#, zapier

I am trying to make WebHooks from Zapier work in F#
Very simply

```
let wc = new System.Net.WebClient()
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol <- System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
let result = wc.DownloadString("WEB HOOK URL GOES HERE")
printfn "%s" result
```

It just times out.
All webhooks are "https"
Some docs:
https://zapier.com/blog/how-use-zapier-webhooks/

Has anyone got this to work and/or can see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tried that on fsi and all working fine using the address from the link and works fine Can't see any other ovbious problem either but dont generally use Zappier ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqxJ9.png)

Comment: Fascinating. That does not work for me. (Which in itself is useful to know)

Comment: Did you check that the given url works in your browser? It might simply be a network issue (maybe a proxy refusing the connection, or something along those lines).

Comment: Yes, it works in my browser

Answer (score 2):

Zapier co-founder here, we are using the ELBSecurityPolicy-2014-01 which you can read about here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-policy-table.html. It isn't uncommon to have a box/libs that default to unsupported SSL protocols/ciphers.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I will have a look. Last week I discovered that the problem is isolated to _my machine_ rather than the office or .NET. Colleagues have been able to make it work. So I have to investigate further into why I just timeout.